# AWS Lambda function unable to establish connection to SQL Server RDS instance

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have written the following small Lambda function in .NET core for testing purposes. It is triggered on a PUT in an S3 bucket, and should show the object name in CloudWatch and insert the object name into a table in an RDS instance.

Here is the code:

```
  public async Task<string> FunctionHandler(S3Event evnt, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            context.Logger.LogLine("context.Logger.LogLine function begin");
            var s3Event = evnt.Records?[0].S3;
            if(s3Event == null)
            {
                context.Logger.LogLine("No S3 Events recorded");
                return null;
            }

            try
            {
                var response = await this.S3Client.GetObjectMetadataAsync(s3Event.Bucket.Name, s3Event.Object.Key);
                context.Logger.LogLine("S3 Key: " + s3Event.Object.Key.ToString());
                var connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionString");
                SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                c.Open(); 

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO LambdaTestTable (ValueText) VALUES('" + s3Event.Object.Key + "')", c);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                c.Close();
                return response.Headers.ContentType;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                context.Logger.LogLine($"Error getting object {s3Event.Object.Key} from bucket {s3Event.Bucket.Name}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.");
                context.Logger.LogLine(e.Message);
                context.Logger.LogLine(e.StackTrace);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

I get the following output in CloudWatch:

> START RequestId: 15c5eddb-8171-11e7-af34-251688cfddb2 Version: $LATEST
>   Console.WriteLine function begin context.Logger.LogLine function begin
>   S3 Key: TaskTemplate.dp Error found Error getting object
>   TaskTemplate.dp from bucket api-dev-dpstorage-s3. Make sure they exist
>   and your bucket is in the same region as this function. A
>   network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing
>   a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not
>   accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL
>   Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Two errors I am unclear on here. Firstly, while CloudWatch successfully shows my object key once the file is PUT to the bucket, it then has an error saying it can't find the object? Secondly, it has a network / instance error trying to connect to the SQL RDS instance. I am using a connection string which is used successfully within an EC2 instance by another application.

Comment: Have you checked this: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-cannot-connect/

Comment: I have thank you, I can confirm that from a VPC and security group point of view, the RDS instance is configured correctly. It can be accessed from other areas of the same AWS region using the same IAM user (e.g. from an EC2 instance running a service which interacts with the SQL server RDS instance in question). I am currently trying a few suggestions around different versions / dependencies of libraries such as System.Data.SqlClient and EntityFrameworkCore but I have to wonder whether Node.js or Python developers have these sorts of issues...

Comment: Also, please ignore the mention of the first error regarding the function reporting that it cant find the object, I realise why that is. I tried to edit the question, but the edit wouldn't save (checking into that)

Comment: Is your Lambda function configured to use the same VPC as the Amazon RDS instance? Is your Lambda function in a public subnet or a private subnet? Do you have a NAT Gateway or NAT Instance? (To connect to both RDS and S3 requires a NAT, which is why I'm asking.)

Comment: Hi John, I have checked the VPC configuration of the Lambda function and found that it is indeed in a different VPC. Changing it to the same VPC as the RDS instance has solved this problem. Thank you! :)